# Laravel: php artistan migrate : The use statement with non-compound name 'IlluminateDatabaseMigrationsMigration' has no effect

Tags: facebook, authentication, laravel

I checked [Troubleshooting "The use statement with non-compound name ... has no effect"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317022/troubleshooting-the-use-statement-with-non-compound-name-has-no-effect)

I am fairly new to Laravel, maybe I am not learning in the right order.
But I found this tutorial which I found fits to my needs, has a demo working online, and github code available.
Tutorial: http://maxoffsky.com/code-blog/integrating-facebook-login-into-laravel-application/#disqus_thread
There are not much others tutorials on Facebook Connect button and found this one perfect, shows up on first google page, et al.

Now, I installed laravel following their official doc using composer.

When I run php artisan migrate, I get the following error:
The use statement with non-compound name 'IlluminateDatabaseMigrationsMigration' has no effect

I must say I'm really noob with Frameworks and OOPHP, maybe I don't learn in the right order.
The Laravel doc is awesome but is not a tutorial, don't hesitate to tell me a good tutorial if you found this question stupid... or that I should have found out the answer myself but my lack of knowledge was the problem.

Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have copied and pasted bad code like I did to get that same error.

In your migration php file change the line that has:

```
use IlluminateDatabaseMigrationsMigration
```

to say:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration
```

The slashes didn't copy from your source code.