# How to fix [ErrorException] the use statement with non-compound name 'App' has no effect error displayed on cmd when php artisan serve command run

Tags: laravel, cmd, localhost, laravel-5, laravel-artisan

[image: result-when type php artisan serve]

When I try php artisan serve command at my terminal it gives below error.Can any body help me to fix this issue?

> **ErrorException**
>   The use statement with non-compound name 'App' has no effect

Comment: Check out this thread - [Stack-overflow Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317022/troubleshooting-the-use-statement-with-non-compound-name-has-no-effect)

Answer (score 3):

remove

```
use App;
```

from your route.php file, it will work for sure. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I hereby post the answer for my own question as I found answer for this and hope this may helpful others in future.

Before : I just used 'use App' only at routes.php 
Now    : When use 'use App\Http\Controllers' problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you add 'use App;' in some of your Laravel files, and artisan is parsing the line as an error.
To know which line/file is the error, go to the log file (storage/logs/) and check it out. Then remove that line from the file.