# Class App\Http\Controllers\SocialFacebookAccountService does not exist error in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, facebook, facebook-php-sdk, laravel-socialite

I am using Socialite for Logging in my users with Facebook. I have done all the processes needed to built the functionality. When I click on "Login with Facebook", it asks for permission and giving permissions on facebook, it redirects me too an error. 
**This is the error link:** [http://localhost:8888/under_dev/mytaswir/public/callback?code=AQDupltbruPf7MokV6N-Mlmrcmqu-QFeKyImrMz8Yp3ViAv128lZBDfPS88Su1q60o6EfFL0_KIy2YH7lztGJrdj0ZDUFZDjR2ucMobLpUGyzPc39ABElZBJko3llqB5xehmZxJMuay7lBHybZ7F6AMxrCN2H0bNhPFPts5_v6Zmb0kfFR7H2A-ha4EXbJzTX6Y98SY9G50HWP1v-KqcUt5ozXfsNIldR19O_dMCEunGLTsf2sKLK76ObEwPdERhW-XzhJv-IdzeHU-Ppw91TWYHjWvBbEajwQH9N-p91VjWNaede7zOKfCBYUiOedzlLRDfz1qv9QghjmceULRk-DwldD0hY1nBv_jSJwVtq_FLhQ&state=UkCIOpg6dqle5dStyvbgtc9se0OiLxGwqWUZyTli#*=*](http://localhost:8888/under_dev/mytaswir/public/callback?code=AQDupltbruPf7MokV6N-Mlmrcmqu-QFeKyImrMz8Yp3ViAv128lZBDfPS88Su1q60o6EfFL0_KIy2YH7lztGJrdj0ZDUFZDjR2ucMobLpUGyzPc39ABElZBJko3llqB5xehmZxJMuay7lBHybZ7F6AMxrCN2H0bNhPFPts5_v6Zmb0kfFR7H2A-ha4EXbJzTX6Y98SY9G50HWP1v-KqcUt5ozXfsNIldR19O_dMCEunGLTsf2sKLK76ObEwPdERhW-XzhJv-IdzeHU-Ppw91TWYHjWvBbEajwQH9N-p91VjWNaede7zOKfCBYUiOedzlLRDfz1qv9QghjmceULRk-DwldD0hY1nBv_jSJwVtq_FLhQ&state=UkCIOpg6dqle5dStyvbgtc9se0OiLxGwqWUZyTli#_=_)

**This is the error screenshot:**
[image: It gives out an error: **Class App\Http\Controllers\SocialFacebookAccountService does not exist**]
It gives out an error: **Class App\Http\Controllers\SocialFacebookAccountService does not exist!

I have made all my Controllers, Service Providers, Aliases, etc.. in the way suggested on this [article](https://appdividend.com/2017/07/12/laravel-facebook-login/).

Please help me get rid of this error. I want the programme to log in my Facebook User into the dashboard.

If you want to see the files, see this [git commit](https://github.com/KumarAbhirup/myTaswir/tree/c07b2b5a3dd38f70dd0f26eed2eeb983469993ab).

**Thanks in advance.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are missing the namespace here: https://github.com/KumarAbhirup/myTaswir/blob/c07b2b5a3dd38f70dd0f26eed2eeb983469993ab/app/Http/Controllers/SocialAuthFacebookController.php#L26

```
  /**
   * Return a callback method from facebook api.
   *
   * @return callback URL from facebook
   */
  public function callback(SocialFacebookAccountService $service)
```

This method belongs to `App\Http\Controllers\SocialAuthFacebookController`, so when the system tries to resolve the class name `SocialFacebookAccountService` from that "location", it will result in `App\Http\Controllers\SocialFacebookAccountService`, and that does not exist.

The class is actually in the namespace `\App\Services`, so you must also use that in this place:

```
  public function callback(\App\Services\SocialFacebookAccountService $service)
```

---

Edit: Fixed error regarding missing leading \, to refer the fully qualified namespace

Comment: Now it gives a different error: Class App\Http\Controllers\App\Services\SocialFacebookAccountService does not exist

Comment: Sorry, leading \ missing - `public function callback(\App\Services\SocialFacebookAccountService $service)` should do the trick then.

Comment: thanks a lot for ur help.. but just some more plz.. now this error comes: **The use statement with non-compound name 'Socialize' has no effect**

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9317022/troubleshooting-the-use-statement-with-non-compound-name-has-no-effect

Comment: hey, I read that already. But that didnt helped.. see this git commit. You might find my mistake here... https://github.com/KumarAbhirup/myTaswir/tree/25c89f3f0463a5728908fbff7a86ecf7b2355462

Comment: Hey, finally after trying hundreds of time, got everything I need. You had a mojor role in solving my problem!